# Run docker containers in detatched mode selectively

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I’m starting up a few containers with a docker-compose.yml file.  I would like all of them to start in detached mode **except** for one, which i would like to run attached.

I can pass the detach flag on the command line with

```
docker-compose up -d
```

But I wonder if it’s possible to specify this in the yml file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try `docker-compose up -d service_name` for the dettached ones and just `docker-compose up service_name` for the other.

Not possible to declare in the compose file as far as I know.